# Create Chart from Query Task?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, chart

I need to create a chart from the result of a query task using Esri JS API.  Note, the chart does not have to be created with Esri API, but the query runs in that.  The result is written to the DOM and can be displayed using an .innerHTML.

So I basically have a number (Query Result) that is given to the DOM that I would like to use to build a chart.  The fun thing is that its a time aware DynamicService and this makes great use of the
[timeslider](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/time_sliderwithdynamiclayer.html) widget to create a great visualization of development over time.  I now wish to add to this with a statistical review.  I am able to return a total built number to the DOM and display that in a DIV, as shown in the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bretwhiteley/h9cLvf8c/).  So its a cool visualization and provides some stats.  the query is running on the same same source data, but on a REST that is not M-enabled.

What I am looking for is to provide a line chart that adds records to it as the number increases - query results returned to the DOM.  I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the mediaInfos charts like this example:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/popup_chart.html